# Building HTTP request dynamically

Tags: java, http, reflection, get

I have an object.

```
public class Query
{
   int id;
   String queryString;
   ....
   ....
   //getters and setters 
}
```

I want dynamically build `HTTP GET` request out of this object.

eg: http://example.com/search?id=12344123&queryString=battlefield

Is there are any elegant way of doing that? Maybe using reflection but not just building it through `StringBuilder`?

Comment: *"Is there are any elegant way of doing that? Maybe using reflection.."*  Wow!  That is the first time I have *ever* heard reflection referred to as 'elegant'.

Comment: What's the issue with creating a factory that takes in a Query and gives back an HttpRequest?

Comment: @Miquel, issue is that I need update a factory class all the time then  I add a new property to `Query` class.

Comment: There is apache commons http library for doing that.

Comment: Both JAX-RS (`javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`) and Spring (`RestTemplate`) have rich APIs for creating syntactically valid GET requests, I suggest you check out one of those.